# Can you send SMS messages using your Google Voice number from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-voice, sms

[Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice) allows you to send text messages to/from an assigned local telephone number.  Unfortunately, it's interface for doing so is rather poor in my opinion.  [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/) has a much better interface for chatting and sending text messages.

Unfortunately, Gmail SMS sends messages from a California number instead of my local Google Voice number.  It isn't a random number though; it appears to have used the same number for years now.  For that reason, I'm unsure if Gmail doesn't support sending SMS text messages using my Google Voice number at all, or my much older Gmail SMS number is taking precedence for some reason.

Can Gmail send text messages using my Google Voice number?

Answer (score 6):

The Email-SMS gateway that Google Voice uses formats email addresses like this in the messages that it sends to you:

`12125551212.12015550189.{some-random-string}@txt.voice.google.com`

The first phone number there is your own, the second is the other person in the conversation. The random string is just that, a bunch of letters, numbers, and punctuation with no apparent rhyme or reason.

However, this email address is re-usable. I just took a SMS message email that I'd received a couple of days ago and grabbed the address. Then I sent a new email message to that address and the recipient received it as a SMS message from my Google Voice number.

(You can't leave the random string out; it's probably some sort of hash to prevent random SMS sending.)

So, it's no help for the first time you send someone an SMS message, but if they send/reply to you (and you're using the Email-SMS gateway feature of Google Voice) you can save the address used to their contact record and can simply use email to send them SMS in the future.

Note: this only appears to work for the Gmail account associated with the Google Voice account sending the message. (Thank you Larry.)

Comment: I don't believe Al Everett's answer is correct at present. Today I tested the theory and partially failed. I was able to send a text to my Google Voice account only when sending the email from the gmail account associated with the Google Voice account. When I attempted to send from a different gmail account, the mail bounced back with Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure). The body of the bounced email indicated a permanent failure to deliver the message.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, the only current way to do it is through your Google Voice administration.

You can receive, send and reply from Google Voice and your text message would show up under your Google Voice number rather than your Gmail address.

I prefere the Gmail interface for texting, but so far it seems as the only way to go.